# SMS message from phone number

Tags: python, sms, smtplib

I'm trying to write a script that will send an SMS message from one phone number to another using smtplib. The script looks like this:

```
import smtplib

message = 'Test'

se = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
se.sendmail('2222222222@vtext.com','1111111111@vtext.com',message)
```

This doesn't crash but I don't actually receive a message on my phone. However, when I change the sender address to my email I DO get the message on my phone. Why doesn't this work when I send an SMS with a real phone number as the sender address?